# How can I override the ToString() method in C#?

Tags: c#, overriding

I want to override the Tostring() method for changing some characters. Is it possible? If yes, How can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As per your question, to *change* some characters in the `ToString` implementation, you need to call the existing `ToString` method by using the `base` keyword:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return base.ToString().Replace("something", "another thing");
}
```

Note that if you forget the `base` keyword it will call itself repeatedly until you get a `StackOverflowException`.

Answer (score 16):

In your class where you want to override it in, add:

```
public override string ToString()
{
  // return your string representation
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Add the following in the class you want to override the ToString function:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    // Add your implementation here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

See example at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.object.aspx).

```
public override String ToString() 
{
    return String.Format("Test {0}", 101);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

All you need is to try to write **public override**, and then Visual Studio will create the method for you like this:

```
 public override string ToString()
 {
      // Implement your own code and return desired string
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone looks for a general answer to "How to override the ToString() method", I've written a post, "[Override ToString() using JSON serialization or something else](http://geekswithblogs.net/mnf/archive/2013/05/04/override-tostring-using-json-serialization-or-something-else.aspx)."

In a summary, the following technologies can be used to simplify creation of ToString():

1. JSON serialization (either DataContractJsonSerializer, JSON.NET or the NuGet package JsonValue).
2. XmlSerialize
3. LINQPad's [dump an arbitrary object to an HTML string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9437947/52277)
4. ServiceStack.Text  [C# .NET Extension method: T.Dump();](http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=202)