# How to implement Dump as the one provided by LinqPad?

Tags: c#, linqpad

Given `(new [] {"a", "b"}).Dump()`, LinqPad provides some very useful print results.

It seems that this extension method is a short hand for `Console.WriteLine`.

**Question**> how to implement this dump for myself?

Answer (score 4):

This thread might be of use to you.
[Is there a library that provides a formatted Dump( ) function like LinqPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032908/is-there-a-library-that-provides-a-formatted-dump-function-like-linqpad)

Comment: I have tried to add LinqPad.exe to my refernece, but I got the following warning.     Warning 1 The referenced assembly "LINQPad" could not be resolved because it has a dependency on "System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which is not in the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". Please remove references to assemblies not in the targeted framework or consider retargeting your project. ConsoleApplication2

Comment: you need to target the full v4 framework - not the cut-down client profile. Check your project properties.

Comment: Or download the .NET 3.5 version of LinqPad

Answer (score 2):

With a lot of hard work.

`Dump` is not a shortcut for `Console.WriteLine`; it's an extremely complicated recursive method which turns arbitrary object graphs into HTML, with special support for collections, `DataTable`s, `Image`s, and a couple of other types.

It also has special output code to format collections of complex objects into tables, and to prevent recursive expansion.

Comment: basically, you tell me to just use it inside Linqpad rather than do it myself:)

Comment: I'm not telling you anything.  It depends what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the `Object Dumper` class that is included in the [Visual C# 2008 Samples](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/cs2008samples/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=8). It won't be in the pretty HTML format used by LINQPad and the other types of output it supports, but the purpose is similar.