# Linqpad Result Pane - run separately or another similar implementation

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, linqpad

I'm running a few windows console programs, and I would like to be able to format text output, display photographs in a scrolling fashion, basically what is implemented in Linqpad.

Is there some framework or a method to run Linqpad result pane without the Linqpad user interface ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement Dump as the one provided by LinqPad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207386/how-to-implement-dump-as-the-one-provided-by-linqpad)

Answer (score 3):

Add a reference to LINQPad.exe (the AnyCPU build) and call `LINQPad.Util.CreateXhtmlWriter` or `LINQPad.Util.ToHtmlString`.