# Dump method c#, plug in needed?

Tags: c#

I have seen  Object.Dump() method where you can see the object created  in the bottom of of the Visual Studio after running. Does anybody know what plug-in I need?

Comment: You could use Json serializer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032908/is-there-a-library-that-provides-a-formatted-dump-function-like-linqpad/6035014#6035014

Comment: Did you look here already?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414214/linqpad-in-visual-studio/38199055#38199055

Answer (score 1):

I think you're referring to [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), which has a `Dump()` extension method to see the object details.  Visual Studio has no built-in extension that I know of.

Comment: Thank you yes, i thought it was vs, but turned out It's linqpad.

Answer (score 1):

You have probably been looking at examples of C# code running inside of LinqPad, which does have a Dump method.

Otherwise, the author created the Dump method.

There is no Dump method in .NET, and I don't know of any "plug-in" (library) that includes one.

Comment: thank you thats what i found out