# How do I convert IEnumerable<T> to string, recursively?

Tags: c#, generics

I want a function that I can call as an alternative to .ToString(), that will show the contents of collections.

I've tried this:

```
public static string dump(Object o) {
    if (o == null) return "null";
    return o.ToString();
}

public static string dump<K, V>(KeyValuePair<K, V> kv) {
    return dump(kv.Key) + "=>" + dump(kv.Value);
}

public static string dump<T>(IEnumerable<T> list) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("{");
    foreach(T t in list) {
        result.Append(dump(t));
        result.Append(", ");
    }
    result.Append("}");
    return result.ToString();
}
```

but the second overload never gets called. For example:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("polo");
Dictionary<int, List<string>> dict;
dict.Add(1, list);
Console.WriteLine(dump(dict));
```

I'm expecting this output:

```
{1=>{"polo", }, }
```

What actually happens is this:
dict is correctly interpreted as an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, List<string>>>`, so the 3rd overload is called.

the 3rd overload calls dump on a KeyValuePair>. This should(?) invoke the second overload, but it doesn't -- it calls the first overload instead.

So we get this output:

```
{[1=>System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]], }
```

which is built from KeyValuePair's .ToString() method.

Why isn't the second overload called? It seems to me that the runtime should have all the information it needs to identify a KeyValuePair with full generic arguments and call that one.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but of possible interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032908/is-there-a-library-that-provides-a-formatted-dump-function-like-linqpad

Comment: Probably has to do with `KeyValuePair` being a struct instead of a class.

Comment: Isn't the problem rather that the third overload isn't called for the `List<string>`? You do get the output from the second overload, but when it dumps the pair it uses the first instead of third overload. Can you try writing out just `dump(list)`? Also: Have you debugged to verify exactly what decisions are made? Step through the code, and get wiser! =)

Comment: `dump(list)` works just fine. `dump(dict.First())` correctly goes to the second `dump`, but when dumping the value, it goes to the first one

Comment: There is no recursion here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(updated)** As mentioned in other answers, the problem is that the compiler does not know that type `V` is actually a `List<string>`, so it just goes to `dump(object)`.

A possible workaround might be to check types at run time. `Type.IsGenericType` will tell you if the type of a variable has generics or not, and `Type.GetGenericArguments` will give you the actual type of those generics.

So you can write a single `dump` method receiving an object and ignoring any generics info. Note that I use the `System.Collections.IEnumerable` interface rather than `System.Collections.Generics.IEnumerable<T>`.

```
public static string dump(Object o)
{
    Type type = o.GetType();

    // if it's a generic, check if it's a collection or keyvaluepair
    if (type.IsGenericType) {
        // a collection? iterate items
        if (o is System.Collections.IEnumerable) {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("{");
            foreach (var i in (o as System.Collections.IEnumerable)) {
                result.Append(dump(i));
                result.Append(", ");
            }
            result.Append("}");
            return result.ToString();

        // a keyvaluepair? show key => value
        } else if (type.GetGenericArguments().Length == 2 &&
                   type.FullName.StartsWith("System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair")) {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            result.Append(dump(type.GetProperty("Key").GetValue(o, null)));
            result.Append(" => ");
            result.Append(dump(type.GetProperty("Value").GetValue(o, null)));
            return result.ToString();
        }
    }
    // arbitrary generic or not generic
    return o.ToString();
}
```

That is: a) a collection is iterated, b) a keyvaluepair shows `key => value`, c) any other object just calls `ToString`. With this code

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("polo");
Dictionary<int, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>() ;
dict.Add(1, list);
Console.WriteLine(dump(list));
Console.WriteLine(dump(dict.First()));
Console.WriteLine(dump(dict));
```

you get the expected output:

```
{marco, }
1 => {marco, }
{1 => {marco, }, }
```

Comment: This definitely seems the correct/only approach -- runtime type checking. Thanks for the example, it's good to know the exact syntax for dealing with generics at runtime!

Answer (score 5):

Generics is a compile time concept, not run time.
In other words the type parametes are resolved at compile time.

In your foreach you call `dump(t)` and t is of type T.
But there is nothing known about T at this point other than that it is an `Object`.
That's why the first overload is called.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. Or more specifically: generics are a run-time concept, but overloads are a compile-time concept. Right?

Answer (score 0):

To call the second version in your `foreach`, you need to specify the template parameters `K` and `V`, otherwise it will always call the first version:

```
dump(t); // always calls first version
dump<K,V>(t); // will call the second
```

How you get the parameter types `K` and `V` is another question....

Comment: This will result in a compiler error as T is not (always) convertible to List<string> (or whatever).