# Diagnostic dump of HttpWebRequest object

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

Is there any good way (other than tediously querying each property) to build a diagnostic dump string for an HttpWebRequest in C#?  For simple objects one can get away with using `new JObject(theObject)`, but that doesn't work for HttpWebRequest (and `toString` is, of course, as useless on HttpWebRequest as it is on any C# object).

Is there any general way to do this for any subset of C# objects (other than using `new JObject` as I already mentioned)?

**Update:**  I've found that using JsonConvert.SerializeObject (one suggestion in Hans' link) does a decent job of dumping the HttpWebRequest (though it doesn't get the request stream).  And I kind of got the System.Net.Tracing stuff to work (though the documentation, as usual for .NET stuff, sucks royally).

Comment: Review [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699466/linqpad-dump-extension-method-i-want-one) for options.

Comment: Are you aware of .NET Tracing: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dgorti/archive/2005/09/18/471003.aspx and you can write your own trace listener.

Comment: I have tried objectdumper but doesnt work if you want to write dumps of objects for debugging check this question that uses linqpad to do it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032908/is-there-a-library-that-provides-a-formatted-dump-function-like-linqpad if that works let me know

Comment: also have you tried using fiddler to see the requests as they are generated instead?

Comment: As @dmportella suggested - if you really need to dump streams along with request headers - consider integrating FiddlerCore into your code. Note that Request/Response streams are not seekable, so you can't read them twice. With intercepting traffic with Fiddler you can see whole request/response just fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This turns out to work pretty well:

```
string httpWebRequestDump(HttpWebRequest hwr)
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(hwr,Formatting.Indented);
}
```

The only problem is that it doesn't dump the associated request stream.  I have not found a way to extract that from the request.

Comment: +1. Note that request/response streams are not seekable, so there is really no way to "preview" them without some redesign of the code.

Comment: This will be very slow and will cause a reference-loop exception

Comment: With namespaces if you want to use it quickly somewhere inside Immediate Window: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(something ,Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

Answer (score 5):

As a quick response I would say override the `ToString()` function by creating your own variant class where the only difference is the `ToString()` method; for example:

```
class HttpWebRequest2 : HttpWebRequest
{
    public HttpWebRequest2(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo SerializationInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext StreamingContext) 
        : base(SerializationInfo, StreamingContext) { }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        // Edit ToString() code here.
        // For example:
        string retval = "[Accept] = " + Accept.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[Address] = " + Address.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[AllowAutoRedirect] = " + AllowAutoRedirect.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[AllowReadStreamBuffering] = " + AllowReadStreamBuffering.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[AllowWriteStreamBuffering] = " + AllowWriteStreamBuffering.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[AuthenticationLevel] = " + AuthenticationLevel.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[AutomaticDecompression] = " + AutomaticDecompression.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[CachePolicy] = " + CachePolicy.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[ClientCertificates] = " + ClientCertificates.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[Connection] = " + Connection.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[ConnectionGroupName] = " + ConnectionGroupName.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[ContentLength] = " + ContentLength.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[ContentType] = " + ContentType.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[ContinueDelegate] = " + ContinueDelegate.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[ContinueTimeout] = " + ContinueTimeout.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[CookieContainer] = " + CookieContainer.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[CreatorInstance] = " + CreatorInstance.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[Credentials] = " + Credentials.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[Date] = " + Date.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[DefaultCachePolicy] = " + DefaultCachePolicy.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[DefaultMaximumErrorResponseLength] = " + DefaultMaximumErrorResponseLength.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[DefaultMaximumResponseHeadersLength] = " + DefaultMaximumResponseHeadersLength.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[Expect] = " + Expect.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[HaveResponse] = " + HaveResponse.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[Headers] = " + Headers.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[Host] = " + Host.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[IfModifiedSince] = " + IfModifiedSince.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[ImpersonationLevel] = " + ImpersonationLevel.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[KeepAlive] = " + KeepAlive.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[MaximumAutomaticRedirections] = " + MaximumAutomaticRedirections.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[MaximumResponseHeadersLength] = " + MaximumResponseHeadersLength.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[MediaType] = " + MediaType.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[Method] = " + Method.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[Pipelined] = " + Pipelined.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[PreAuthenticate] = " + PreAuthenticate.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[ProtocolVersion] = " + ProtocolVersion.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[Proxy] = " + Proxy.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[ReadWriteTimeout] = " + ReadWriteTimeout.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[Referer] = " + Referer.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[RequestUri] = " + RequestUri.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[SendChunked] = " + SendChunked.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[ServerCertificateValidationCallback] = " + ServerCertificateValidationCallback.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[ServicePoint] = " + ServicePoint.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[SupportsCookieContainer] = " + SupportsCookieContainer.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[Timeout] = " + Timeout.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[TransferEncoding] = " + TransferEncoding.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing] = " + UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[UseDefaultCredentials] = " + UseDefaultCredentials.ToString() 
        + "\r\n[UserAgent] = " + UserAgent.ToString();
        return retval;

    }
}
```

---

### For the request stream:

For the request stream how about copying it to a memory stream? Along the lines of:

```
int count = 0;
do
{
  count = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
  memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
  Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
}
while (count != 0);
result = memoryStream.ToArray(); // or ToString() etc. as it takes you fancy/suits your needs :)
```

this would then allow you to leave the original requeststream alone and use the copy in the memory stream to print/store etc as you need.

---

Which will return a string with all the values that can have getters in `HttpWebRequest`:)

All you have to do is use `HttpWebRequest2()` instead and it should be fine:)

Let me know if that helps, or if you need more info/different way of doing it:)

Answer (score 3):

I liked GMasucci's answer better than JSON serialization because the serialization did not extract the values of the Headers.

I modified GMasucci's answer to be an extension method and use StringBuilder and AppendFormat so that nulls don't blow it up, so if you up-vote this answer, please up-vote his as well. I commented out what seem to be deprecated properties too:

```
public static String ToStringReadable(this HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendFormat("[Accept] = {0}", request.Accept);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[Address] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.Address);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[AllowAutoRedirect] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.AllowAutoRedirect);
        //sb.AppendFormat("{0}[AllowReadStreamBuffering] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.AllowReadStreamBuffering);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[AllowWriteStreamBuffering] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[AuthenticationLevel] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.AuthenticationLevel);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[AutomaticDecompression] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.AutomaticDecompression);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[CachePolicy] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.CachePolicy);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[ClientCertificates] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.ClientCertificates);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[Connection] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.Connection);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[ConnectionGroupName] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.ConnectionGroupName);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[ContentLength] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.ContentLength);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[ContentType] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.ContentType);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[ContinueDelegate] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.ContinueDelegate);
        //sb.AppendFormat("{0}[ContinueTimeout] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.ContinueTimeout);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[CookieContainer] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.CookieContainer);
        //sb.AppendFormat("{0}[CreatorInstance] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.CreatorInstance);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[Credentials] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.Credentials);
        //sb.AppendFormat("{0}[Date] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.Date);
        //sb.AppendFormat("{0}[DefaultCachePolicy] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.DefaultCachePolicy);
        //sb.AppendFormat("{0}[DefaultMaximumErrorResponseLength] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.DefaultMaximumErrorResponseLength);
        //sb.AppendFormat("{0}[DefaultMaximumResponseHeadersLength] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.DefaultMaximumResponseHeadersLength);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[Expect] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.Expect);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[HaveResponse] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.HaveResponse);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[Headers] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.Headers);
        //sb.AppendFormat("{0}[Host] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.Host);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[IfModifiedSince] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.IfModifiedSince);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[ImpersonationLevel] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.ImpersonationLevel);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[KeepAlive] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.KeepAlive);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[MaximumAutomaticRedirections] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[MaximumResponseHeadersLength] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.MaximumResponseHeadersLength);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[MediaType] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.MediaType);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[Method] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.Method);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[Pipelined] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.Pipelined);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[PreAuthenticate] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.PreAuthenticate);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[ProtocolVersion] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.ProtocolVersion);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[Proxy] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.Proxy);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[ReadWriteTimeout] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.ReadWriteTimeout);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[Referer] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.Referer);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[RequestUri] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.RequestUri);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[SendChunked] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.SendChunked);
        //sb.AppendFormat("{0}[ServerCertificateValidationCallback] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[ServicePoint] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.ServicePoint);
        //sb.AppendFormat("{0}[SupportsCookieContainer] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.SupportsCookieContainer);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[Timeout] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.Timeout);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[TransferEncoding] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.TransferEncoding);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[UseDefaultCredentials] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.UseDefaultCredentials);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[UserAgent] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.UserAgent);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified GMasucci's and jaybro's answers to use HttpRequest, for cases when it is used instead of HttpWebRequest.

```
public static String ToStringReadable (HttpRequest request)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[AcceptTypes] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.AcceptTypes);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[AnonymousID] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.AnonymousID);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[ApplicationPath] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.ApplicationPath);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[Browser] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.Browser);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[ClientCertificate] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.ClientCertificate);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[ContentEncoding] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.ContentEncoding);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[ContentLength] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.ContentLength);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[ContentType] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.ContentType);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[Cookies] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.Cookies);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[CurrentExecutionFilePath] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.CurrentExecutionFilePath);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[CurrentExecutionFilePathExtension] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.CurrentExecutionFilePathExtension);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[FilePath] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.FilePath);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[Files] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.Files);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[Filter] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.Filter);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[Form] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.Form);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[Headers] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.Headers);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[HttpChannelBinding] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.HttpChannelBinding);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[HttpMethod] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.HttpMethod);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[InputStream] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.InputStream);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[IsAuthenticated] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.IsAuthenticated);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[IsLocal] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.IsLocal);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[IsSecureConnection] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.IsSecureConnection);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[Params] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.Params);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[Path] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.Path);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[PathInfo] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.PathInfo);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[PhysicalApplicationPath] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.PhysicalApplicationPath);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[PhysicalPath] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.PhysicalPath);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[QueryString] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.QueryString);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[RawUrl] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.RawUrl);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[ReadEntityBodyMode] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.ReadEntityBodyMode);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[RequestContext] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.RequestContext);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[RequestType] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.RequestType);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[ServerVariables] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.ServerVariables);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[TimedOutToken] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.TimedOutToken);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[TlsTokenBindingInfo] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.TlsTokenBindingInfo);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[TotalBytes] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.TotalBytes);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[Unvalidated] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.Unvalidated);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[Url] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.Url);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[UrlReferrer] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.UrlReferrer);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[UserAgent] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.UserAgent);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[UserHostAddress] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.UserHostAddress);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[UserHostName] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.UserHostName);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}[UserLanguages] = {1}", Environment.NewLine, request.UserLanguages);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions are pretty much code, plus you'll have to do a lot of things
to keep that code working in the production environment for a long time.

And there could be many other problems you have to solve
only with the `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject` solution:

- recursion in objects
- non-serializable objects
- exceptions
- depth
- ...

Plus you always want to log more info like:

- when the event happened
- callstack
- which threead
- what was in the web session
- ...

There is the best solution that solves all of this and much more.
**Use this Nuget package: [Desharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Desharp/).**
It's for the **web and also for desktop applications**. Very addictive.
See it's **[Desharp Github documentation](https://github.com/debug-sharp/desharp)**. It has **many configuration options**.

Just call anywhere:

```
Desharp.Debug.Log(yourRequestInstance);
```

Plus more:

```
Desharp.Debug.Log(anyException);
Desharp.Debug.Log(anyCustomValueObject);
Desharp.Debug.Log(anyNonserializableObject);
Desharp.Debug.Log(anyFunc);
Desharp.Debug.Log(anything, Desharp.Level.EMERGENCY); // you can store into different files
Desharp.Debug.Dump(anything); // you can dump into browser floating bar
```

There are a few web demos:

- [Web Basic Application](https://github.com/debug-sharp/example-web-basic)
- [Web MVC Application](https://github.com/debug-sharp/example-web-mvc)
- [Web Forms Application](https://github.com/debug-sharp/example-web-forms)

Try to checkout any of them and what is possible to dump or log on HDD:

- it can save the log in nice HTML (or in TEXT format, configurable)
- it's possible to write optionally in background thread (configurable)
- it has options for max objects depth and max strings length (configurable)
- it uses loops for iteratable objects and backward reflection for everything else,
  indeed for **anything you can find in .NET environment**.

I believe it will help.