# View contents of HttpWebRequest without tools(C#)

Tags: c#, http, debugging, request

I want to send a put request with some json strings to a server some time in the future. I want to compare the request Im sending to the requirements I have been given, but I do not have access to that server yet so I cant test if the request Im sending is looking the way it should. The only thing I found would be ToString'ing my httpWebRequest (like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25046967/diagnostic-dump-of-httpwebrequest-object)), which is not what I need.

Is there a way to read exactly what I'm sending after (or before) I send it into the void? Or alternatively, is there a way to send a request to myself and read it that way?

Edit: I cannot install foreign software on my workstation. While using a tool like Wireshark probably solves the answer for the general public, I still need a way to do this programmatically.

Edit2: Searching for the topic may have not resulted in anything, but a random topic on the right that SO suggested actually has (almost exactly) what I wanted and all it takes is copy pasting something into the web.config file. Implementing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25683524/7350797) puts (amongst other things) all the connections as well as their contents into the debug console.

Comment: There are probably dummy/diagnostic http endpoints, but that is a question for software recommendations stack exchange then. If you are able to just send the requests I would use fiddler or wireshark to see if the data on the wire look like I need them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an HTTP debugging tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler). It acts like a proxy and can let you view the request and response of HTTP requests your program sends.

Here's how to use it with HttpWebRequest: [Get HTTP requests and responses made using HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse to show in Fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470634/get-http-requests-and-responses-made-using-httpwebrequest-httpwebresponse-to-sho)

If you aren't allowed to install Fiddler you could think about making your own version of Fiddler in c# to capture traffic [How to create a simple proxy in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226784/how-to-create-a-simple-proxy-in-c)

Comment: I should have mentioned that I cannot install foreign software on my workstation. My bad

Comment: @SvenEngling yes please add that to your question