# Is there: C# literals library

Tags: c#, debugging, extension-methods, literals, render-to-string

Is there a `ToString` C# library for different data structures, and built in classes?

Same as extension methods libraries? I imagine many developers use them for debugging, seeing what the data contains.

For example: `Debug.Writeline(dict);` may give me the following:

```
new Dictionary<string,string>() {{ "abc", "def" } , {"lmn", "opq"}};
```

or a different style.

Thanks.

Comment: Most people just use the debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to try out this library: http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=202. Anyway somebody else made a similar question before: [How to use the LinqPad .Dump() extension method in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699466/linqpad-dump-extension-method-i-want-one)

Comment: the json serializer mentioned in that question was exactly right for my needs.