# LinqPad Dump from DLL

Tags: c#, xhtml, linqpad

I would like to be able to call Dump from my DLL and code below returns raw HTML result.  How can I render it, or what is the correct approach?

**Method**

```
public static string Dump<T>(this T obj)
{
    var writer = LINQPad.Util.CreateXhtmlWriter();
    writer.Write(obj);
    return writer.ToString();
}
```

**Call**

```
Debug.WriteLine(myObject.Dump());
```

**Result on LINQPad**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
      <meta name="Generator" content="LINQ to XML, baby!" />
      <style type='text/css'>
        ...
      </style>
  </head>
<body>
<div>
...
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQPad - Dump extension method - I want one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699466/linqpad-dump-extension-method-i-want-one)

Comment: @DaveShaw please remove the message says "This question may already have an answer here ...".  This question is related to the format of the result (display issue) not about the retrieving the result.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Joe Albahari, adding LinqPad.exe as reference allows us to use Dump function from the library so no implementation is needed.