# Using LinqPad's LinqPad.Util.CreateXhtmlWriter() Avaliable in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, linqpad

Using the `Dump()` method in a manner similar to this post  [LinqPad Dump from DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730719/linqpad-dump-from-dll), 
is extremely convenient. While I understand that we will probably not see a .NET Core release of `LINQPad` for some time (if ever) given the lack of support for WPF, is there a way to use the namespace `LINQPad.Util` (which I am assuming has no WPF dependencies) in .NET Core?

As I understand it, the way in which other people have done this is to add a reference to `LinqPad.exe` in the project, but .NET Core projects do not support this (correct me if I am wrong).

Furthermore, I would like to use the `Dump()` method in my .NET Core projects which target Linux, thus it seems that even if I were to be able to reference an `.exe` in .NET Core, I would still have problems since Linux will not natively run an `.exe` file intended for Windows (not using Wine of course, which would not be very stable).

I suppose I could decompile the source and repackage the `LINQPad.Util` namespace to be .NET Core compatible, but that seems like it might not be in the spirit of the copyright agreement.

If there is an easy way to accomplish this, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: What do you specifically need from `Util`? I think you will have to roll your own versions...

Comment: @NetMage I do not know what I need specifically. I only know that in .NET Standard, all I need to do is add a reference to the LinqPad `.exe` then add `using LINQPad`. That allows me to use `LINQPad.Util.CreateXhtmlWriter()` in my code. I do not know how much of `Util` I will need to support that method.

Comment: Using that would require re-writing Dump(), which certainly can be done, but is not for the faint of heart. I think you would be better off suggesting Joe sell a DLL for Linux.

Comment: I considered asking him to do that, but I figured I would check here first to make sure I wasn't missing something easy. I definitely think with the way the .NET ecosystem is moving, there will be a market for at least some of LinqPad's components to be released for use with .NET Core.

Comment: I'm not sure that Linqpad.exe is being 'run' when used as a referenced library. I had the impression you can use it like a dll and ignore the fact that it's also runnable.

Comment: I just tried a simple console application, and `CreateXhtmlWriter()` failed on System.Drawing.SolidBrush - so I guess Linqpad is written for a different set of libraries. Here's a [comment](http://forum.linqpad.net/discussion/1417/net-core-2-0-support-queries)