# Extract text from string between commas

Tags: c#

I want to extract only those words between two commas. 
So, if the string is  Ab Java, DE, 78801 The answer must be DE
 I have tried this code but it is not working

```
string search = "Ab  Java, DE, 78801 ";
int index = search.IndexOf(",");
string result = search.Substring(search.IndexOf(",") ,index);
MessageBox.Show(result);
```

Comment: Your string has _always_ two commas?

Comment: Yes It always have two commas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your string has *always* 2 commas, you can use [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) for it like;

```
string search = "Ab  Java, DE, 78801 ";
Console.WriteLine(search.Split(',')[1]); // DE
```

Remember, this will you generate `DE` with an extra white space before it.

[image]

If you don't want that white space, you can use [`TrimStart()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to remove it.

```
Console.WriteLine(search.Split(',')[1].TrimStart()); //DE
```

Comment: What is this `Dump()` method?

Comment: @Shaharyar It is an extension method of LINQPad. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699466/linqpad-dump-extension-method-i-want-one I used this tool to generate some code examples but looks like it might be confusing sometimes. Deleted it.

Comment: @SonerGönül Thanks for the explanation. I think downvoter also didn't know about this method :)

Answer (score 3):

Your start and end in your Substring resolve to the same value.

Try using split and getting the second item, of course this assumes that your input always follows the pattern in your example. Otherwise you'll need to do something more complicated.

```
string[] searchItems = search.Split(',');
string result = searchItems[1].Trim(); // will output DE
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
string[] splitedStr=search.Split(',');
string NewStr=splitedStr[1].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your string always has just two commas, then:

```
search.Split(", ")[1]
```

will give you the desired text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
String str = "Ab  Java, DE, 78801 ";
String[] myStrings = str.split(",");
String marco = myStrings[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This. It May work...

```
string[] arrayStr = search.Split(',');
int len = arrayStr.Length;
for(int i =1;i<=len-2;i++)
{
   MessageBox.Show(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is something I would have solved using regular expressions. It might be slower than the `String.Split` solutions but it is way easier to read - in particular if the pattern is going to evolve over time.

The solution would than look like this:

```
string search = "Ab  Java, DE, 78801 ";
Regex r = new Regex(", *(.*?) *,", RegexOptions.Compiled);
Console.WriteLine(r.Match(search).Groups[1].ToString());
```

This writes `DE` without surrounding spaces. The regex instance should be a static member of your class, since I assume this is happening within a loop ...