# how can i get string between two commas?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a string like:

43965.96000,16933.986,404689.986,5814892.171,77.464,**52.47585589**,13.59670032,77.464,0.675,-0.223

I want to just keep the string which is bold in characters between commas. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you have a piece of code that you are trying to use and doesn't work? That would help us help you. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What makes this string different to the others? How do you find it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract text from string between commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365847/extract-text-from-string-between-commas)

Comment: You know, if you had just typed the title of your question into google, you would have had your answer much faster.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve it yourself? What didn't work?

Comment: Here is your desired result: `string result = "52.47585589";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To take your question literally, you could do write a method to split the string by comma and just take the element at the 5th index:

```
string ParseData(string data)
{
    return data.Split(',')[5];
}
```

So you'll be able to do something like:

```
string data = "43965.96000,16933.986,404689.986,5814892.171,77.464,52.47585589,13.59670032,77.464,0.675,-0.223";

string result = ParseData(data); // Result = "52.47585589"
```