# FileNotFound Exception when referencing LinqPad.exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linqpad

I am trying to use LinqPad's dump feature (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9437947/3375305) from within Visual Studio. (.netCore 1.1 Console App).

I have added a reference to `LinqPad.exe`, but whenever I try and run the program, a `File Not Found` exception is thrown.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'LINQPad, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=21353812cd2a2db5'. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.'

I have tried `LinqPad 5.10`, `5.10 AnyCPU`, `5.21 AnyCPU (Beta)`

Comment: where you put LinqPad.exe?

Comment: It is in the default install location. When the project is built, LinqPad.exe gets copied into the bin folder.

Comment: Do this [the correct way](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LINQPad/4.51.3).